# Change protocol return type for method

Tags: swift, polymorphism, protocols

I have a little problem with my Protocol "Model" and a Class "Device" that conforms to "Model."
In my Protocol I have a function which has a return value "Model". In my class, I have this implementation function and want to change the return type from "Model" to "Device". But if I change this, i have to add the original function again.

My Model protocol:

```
protocol Model {
    func fromJSON(jsonString : String) -> Model
}
```

My Device Class:

```
class Device : Model {
    func fromJSON(jsonString: String) -> Model {
        var jsonObj = JSON(jsonString)
        var device = Device()
        return device
    }
}
```

When I try to assign the result of this function to a Device variable, I get this error-message:

> Cannot assign a value of type "Model" to a value of type "Device"

```
let jsonString: String = "MY ARRAY";
var device2 = Device()
device2 = Device().fromJSON(jsonString)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `Model` protocol makes a promise:

```
func fromJSON(jsonString : String) -> Model
```

It promises to return *some* `Model`. It doesn't promise to return the same kind of `Model` as the implementer. If you mean that, it's called `Self`.

```
protocol Model {
    func fromJSON(jsonString : String) -> Self
}
```

With classes, this is a bit of a pain to implement. Ideally your Device should be a struct, which makes it trivial. But if you mark the class `final`, then it's fine as well:

```
protocol Model {
    static func fromJSON(jsonString : String) -> Self
}

final class Device : Model {
    class func fromJSON(jsonString: String) -> Device {
        let device = Device()
        return device
    }
}
```

But really, this whole protocol makes no sense. What you really want is a initializer:

```
protocol Model {
    init(jsonString : String)
}

class Device : Model {
    required init(jsonString: String) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now i have another problem. Now the function in my subclass has an error: Method "fromJSON" in non-final class "Device" must return "SELF" to conform to protocol "Model"

Comment: Sorry; yes. Ideally you should mark the class final, but if you plan to subclass, then you should return Self there. When possible, use structs rather than classes. They don't have these complications.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I want to change the type from class to struct. But now i have a problem with a function from a different class. The function is called toJsonString(object AnyObject). I call this function in Device Struct with classobject.toJsonString(self). But after changing from class to struct I get this error: Cannot invoke "toJsonString" with an argument list of type (Device). Any idea?

Comment: A struct is not an AnyObject. It's an Any (though typically, you should make `toJSONString` be a method on the object rather than a function you pass objects to).